# How do global variables work in recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
count=0
global count
def fact(n):
    count+=1
    if n==1:return 1
    else:return(n*fact(n-1))
print(fact(5))
```

When the variable count is declared as global, is the variable count accessible in all recursive frames?

The above code doesn't work, however the below code works. Can someone explain why?

```
count=0
def fact(n):
    global count
    count+=1
    if n==1:return 1
    else:return(n*fact(n-1))
print(fact(5))
```

Why is it necessary to specify global inside the function, when the entire point of global variables is to use them inside functions?

Answer (score 3):

`count += 1` is a *local* assignment that shadows the global `count`. It doesn't matter that there is a global variable available to increment. You have to declare the global in order for the assignment to affect the global.

Using the `global` keyword outside the function doesn't do anything; it has to be used *in* a functionto mark a name that would otherwise be local to the function scope as a global instead.